# The class 'FirebaseStorage' doesn't have an unnamed constructor

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

i've cloned a git to build an app. In the storage section i've the following code:

```
class StorageRepo {
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(
    storageBucket: ''
  );
```

However it give me the error:

> The class 'FirebaseStorage' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.

What's wrong?

Comment: This is what i've added for the storage, not what i've copied!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/) Doug linked, creating a `FirebaseStorage` object for a specific bucket is done with:

```
firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(
      bucket: 'secondary-storage-bucket');
```

Comment: i've read that and tryied... but i get the error "Undefined name 'firebase_storage'

Comment: My guess is that you're import looks different than the one in that same documentation page then: `import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;`. If you just used `import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'`, you can also drop the `firebase_storage` from the class and constructor references in your code.